# Overriding the default session manager with embedded tomcat 7 java

Tags: session, tomcat

I am trying to override the tomcat session manager with an embedded tomcat.

These are the steps preformed in-order to load the context.xml that defines the manager entity.

```
..
Context context = tomcat.addWebapp(contextPath, appBase);       
File configFile = new File ("D:\\context.xml");
context.setConfigFile(configFile.toURI().toURL());
tomcat.start();
..
```

The session manager seems to be recognized as it's constructor is being invoked but the startInternal() method is never invoked and the session manager being used is the old tomcat session manager.

The weird thing is that when defining the same configuration in a non embedded tomcat, the session manager is being overridden without problems.

Would appriciate any help on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Non embedded tomcat uses server.xml and embedded tomcat does not uses server.xml file rather we need to pass the arguments in the method.

Comment: First of all thanks for your quick answer. Sadly I don't have a clue as to why the log files aren't being generated. Ill try looking into it when I get to that point. can you please be more specific about what arguments I need to pass using what method? Thanks again..

Comment: @user840184 - I removed the follow-on question from your answer, because it doesn't really belong there.  Feel free to ask a new question on the topic, so that others can help you out.